# Async integration events needed sync

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, ddd-service

I thought of two domains. One is the game domain which handles the joining of the players to a game and the game itself until finishing.
Another domain is the ranking which will be calculated based on the skill of a user and the game result. The relevant game events (e.g. player left, game finished) are broadcasted as integration events.
I read at multiple sites that integration events should be sent asynchronously. However, I need the new score for each player when the game is finished to be displayed. This doesn’t work as it is async. Did I draw my domain boundaries wrong? Are there any other options?